# How can I get Firefox to use Dolphin instead of Nautilus?

Tags: nautilus, firefox, dolphin

I am using dolphin as my file manager and when I download something via firefox, I right click the download dialog and choose "open folder", I always get nautilus.

Why doesn't firefox open the folder with dolphin?
Thanks

Note: I tried adding the tag "dolphin" but because of my low rep I can't create new tags :(

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get Dolphin in the file-picker dialog, install the package "kmozillahelper" from the standard repositories.

```
sudo apt-get install kmozillahelper
```

Set the filepicker-variable in in Firefox by visiting the URL about:config.

[More information here](http://kubuntuforums.net/forums/index.php?topic=3113144.new)

Comment: The More Information link is dead.

Comment: As is the package itself: `E: Unable to locate package kmozillahelper`.

Answer (score 7):

```
sudo apt-get install kmozillahelper
```

is not more available.

## How to use dolphin to open folder in firefox

When I installed KDE and Firefox this feature actually worked – I downloaded a file, clicked on “open containing folder”, and Dolphin would happily pop with the respective folder open.

However, when I installed a few more apps,  Firefox started calling Gwent or other app to “open the folder”.

Solution:

In the file `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, find `inode/directory` and make `kde4-dolphin.desktop` on first such as:

```
inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;
```

Comment: I did it and it did not help...

Comment: I needed to use `org.kde.dolphin.desktop` instead of `kde4-dolphin.desktop`.

Comment: easier to run `mimeopen -d /` and pick Dolphin from the list

Comment: @ewanm89 I wish you posted this as an answer. I will post this on your behalf as a community post. Thanks!

Comment: @Autodidact I'm trying to remember why I didn't, I do note that was 2021 and this is a 2013 question.

Answer (score 5):

As user162413 stated, kmozillahelper is no longer avaliable. His solution however did not work for me.

Instead, one from [dragly](http://dragly.org/2013/02/18/set-open-containing-folder-to-use-dolphin-and-pdf-files-to-use-okular-in-firefox-on-kubuntu/) did the trick:

Open up `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list` and change line

```
inode/directory=nautilus.desktop
```

to

```
inode/directory=kde4/dolphin.desktop
```

Works without need to restart Firefox.

Comment: Didn't work for me either. Is there another possible solution?

Comment: Not working as well. Can you please post the version of OS and application?

Comment: this is the correct answer 16.04 LTS -- works for me

Answer (score 1):

After installing Firefox in Kubuntu there was not default file manager associated with the browser.

1. Pressing the grey/green "Display the progress of ongoing downloads" arrow, just next to the search engine box in the head (right hand/top) of the browser (my Firefox version is 25.0.1), "Show All Downloads" menu was displayed.
2. When I pressed it "Library" window opened and I pressed on "Open Containing Folder" button.
3. Then "Launch Application" dialogue pops up with "Choose an Application" suggestion.
4. Pressing "Choose..." I selected `/usr/bin/` as folder and chose `dolphin` as the program.  Dolphin can be selected as default application using the check box.

By the way - trying to install kmozillahelper in Kubuntu I got "E: Unable to locate package kmozillahelper". That's right - it's not available any more.

Comment: Well... The problem is if firefox is already assigned a program, then you won't get the "Choose an application" suggestion

Answer (score 1):

For those still having this issue, I found a slightly easier way:

1. Open the Default Applications control module (KDE menu -> search for Default)
2. Select the File Manager list
3. Ensure that Dolphin is selected

   - if it is already selected, reselect by clicking on another option then back to Dolphin
4. click Apply
5. test

This worked for me.  YMMV, but this would be a much better solution rather than editing the MIME configuration manually.

Comment: Did not work me, Firefox still uses Gnome Files :-/

Comment: This worked for me, running KDE on Ubuntu 20.4.

Answer (score 1):

A [workaround](https://www.kubuntuforums.net/showthread.php/70383-Firefox-s-file-dialogue-box-runs-like-crap?p=389565&viewfull=1#post389565) that worked for me was to set `MOZ_USE_XINPUT2=1` when launching Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem. Installing KDE for Ubuntu and Firefox not using Dolphin. The only thing that worked for me was uninstalling Nautilus and everything GNOME related completely.

Answer (score 0):

Run `mimeopen -d /` and pick Dolphin from the list.

Promoting comment from @ewanm89 to answer (with thanks)!