# How can I get Firefox to use Dolphin instead of Nautilus by default?

Tags: firefox, dolphin

I installed Kubuntu, and want to use Dolphin when I try to save a file or open a new file, but firefox always use Nautilus, how can I change this?

I find this question, but it does not work for me: [How can I get Firefox to use Dolphin instead of Nautilus?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2495/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-use-dolphin-instead-of-nautilus)

I can neither download the kmozillahelper package, nor find the filepicker-variable in my firefox.

my Ubuntu: 12.10
my firefox: 16.0.2

Answer (score 1):

use dolphin to open folder in firefox

When I installed KDE and Firefox this feature actually worked – I downloaded a file, clicked on “open containing folder”, and Dolphin would happily pop with the respective folder open.
However, when I installed a few more apps,  Firefox started calling Gwent or other app to “open the folder”.

Solution:

In the file /usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache , find “inode/directory” and make “kde4-dolphin.desktop” on first such as:

inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;kde4-gwenview.desktop;kde4-kfmclient_dir.desktop;

here the Link: http://s8dragon.wordpress.com/2011/01/16/use-dolphin-to-open-folder-in-firefox/

Answer (score 0):

For those still having this issue, I found a slightly easier way:

- Open the Default Applications control module (KDE menu -> search for Default)
- Select the File Manager list
- Ensure that Dolphin is selected

  - if it is already selected, reselect by clicking on another option then back to Dolphin
- click Apply
- test

This worked for me.  YMMV, but this would be a much better solution rather than editing the MIME configuration manually.

Russell.

Comment: I just tried and it did not work for me. 
BTW I use a Ubuntu 21.10 install with initially GNOME where I switched to KDE afterwards.