# Firefox does not open dolphin for inode/directory in kubuntu 15.04

Tags: nautilus, firefox, kubuntu, kde, dolphin

this question has been asked multiple times like [1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/2495/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-use-dolphin-instead-of-nautilus) and [2](https://askubuntu.com/questions/219119/how-can-i-get-firefox-to-use-dolphin-instead-of-nautilus-by-defalut), but their solutions won't work anymore. Probably because of Plasma 5 and the new firefox versions.

So I am using Kubuntu 15.04, Firefox 40.0 and KDE Plasma Desktop. My default file manager is dolphin. Except Firefox opens another file manager - probably some gnome file manager, because it has no info menu to see its name. But `ps -ef` suggests, it is nautilus.

**What I tried so far**

1. In `/usr/share/applications/mimeinfo.cache`, change to `inode/directory=kde4-dolphin.desktop;(..)`
2. In `/usr/share/applications/defaults.list`, change to `inode/directory=kde4/dolphin.desktop` (why use a slash here? See [this answer](https://askubuntu.com/a/401477/132305)).
3. installing package `kmozillahelper` - but this is no longer available.
4. checking xdg-open by verifying that `xdg-open $PWD` opens dolphin. This works, but not for firefox.
5. removing `rm ~/.mozilla/firefox/<profile>/mimeTypes.rdf` did not work either, as [suggested here](https://askubuntu.com/a/113090/132305).
6. Verified, that there is probably no user setting overriding dolphin with nautilus:

   `[~] $ grep -R nautilus  .local/share/mime
   [~] $`

So, I'm sorry to re-ask this question, but things have changed. How do I let firefox open folders (download locations) in dolphin?

Comment: Just compíled `kmozillahelper`, but I still cannot find the "filepicker" variable. Also, I consider it too complicated for average users who don't want too compile anything.

Comment: Same issue with `nemo` - I end up symlinking baking the nautilus excutable and symlinking a new one from the `nemo` one as suggested [here](http://askubuntu.com/a/260249/178596) - probably not recommended for varying reasons, and dolphin is different enough that a wrapper script may be better. Apart from that, removing all trace of `nautilus.desktop` from the mimelists/caches or removing nautilus altogether may work.

Comment: I cecked and saw that in fact nautilus is a link to dolphin (inside `~/.local/...`). So I really don't know what else to do.

Answer (score 2):

I had the exact same problem, although I tried different things on the web, this was what helped me in the end.

```
ln -s /usr/share/applications/kde4/dolphin.desktop ~/.local/share/applications/nautilus-folder-handler.desktop
```

I found the solution thanks to this bug report in audacious.
https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/audacious/+bug/1196339

As I said, I did try other things before, so maybe it was a combo of the things I did, but I think linking the dolphin.desktop file to the (default) application which should be nautilus-folder-handler.desktop should do the trick.

Hope it helps.

EDIT: After going through all the steps again, I think you also need the following.

```
$ pwd
~/.local/share/applications

$ cat kde-dolphin.desktop 
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=dolphin
MimeType=inode/directory
Name=dolphin
NoDisplay=true
Type=Application

$ cat default.list 
[Default Applications]
x-directory/normal=kde-dolphin.desktop;kde-kfmclient_dir.desktop;
```

Comment: this is a better method from this same user. thanks. https://askubuntu.com/a/401477/138912

Comment: creating the .desktop files and defaults.list inside ~/.local/share/applications worked perfectly for Chromium